# How to mock a custom step using JenkinsPipelineUnit?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-pipeline-unit

I'm using [JenkinsPipelineUnit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit/) to test a pipeline. I define a custom step, like so:

```groovy
// vars/getOnlineNodes.groovy
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

def call() {
    Jenkins.get().nodes
            .findAll { it.toComputer().isOnline() }
            .collect { it.selfLabel.name }
}
```

and mock it in my test:

```groovy
helper.registerAllowedMethod('getOnlineNodes', [], { ['node1', 'node2', 'node3'] })
```

But it throws an exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletException`. How should I do this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution to this [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit/issues/49#issuecomment-316659638). Basically, if you mock your custom step (a function) before running the script, it will override the mocking because the library will be loaded when calling `runScript('my-script.jenkins')`:

```groovy
helper.registerAllowedMethod('getOnlineNodes', [], { ['node1', 'node2', 'node3'] })
runScript('my-script.jenkins')
```

What you should do is to load the script, then mock the step, and then run the script, like so:

```groovy
def script = loadScript('my-script.jenkins')
helper.registerAllowedMethod('getOnlineNodes', [], { ['node1', 'node2', 'node3'] })
script.run()
```

Comment: I find that this doesn't always work for me. I can't figure it out. I know you have to exactly match the function signature, and i'm doing that, and not getting any errors, but the mock is not working and the real function gets called instead. It's mostly an issue with functions defined within the script i'm running - external functions are easily mocked.

Comment: @MaxCascone: Maybe you should minimize the project to narrow down the root cause? If that does not help, could you share it?